# XAMPP will not start up

Tags: apache, xampp

I am unable to get [XAMPP](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/) working.

Apache doesn't work. It fails with the following log messages:

```
16:02:59  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
16:02:59  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
16:02:59  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
16:02:59  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
16:02:59  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
16:02:59  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
16:02:59  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums
```

[That is a screenshot of a window that appeared after I have tried to run xampp.start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5Rfd.png)

I have changed Skype's settings.

I have changed Apache's ports in the conf files. I have changed ports in XAMPP.

Comment: Looks like your php installation is not defined in PATH

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please always provide source code, error messages and other textual information as inline plain text rather than external pictures. Text is searchable, reusable and normally easier to read.

Comment: Lo siento, Alvaro. I suppose I can copy it here in a sec

Comment: @mr_sudaca could you tell me how to do it? I'm sorry. I'm a beginning beginner !

Comment: The linked screenshot clearly states there's a problem with PHP configuration in a specific line of a specific Apache settings file. Please have a look there.

Comment: I found this `<Directory "/xampp/phpMyAdmin">
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
        Require local
        ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
    </Directory>

    Alias /webalizer "/xampp/webalizer/"
    <Directory "/xampp/webalizer">
        <IfModule php5_module>
      <Files "webalizer.php">
       php_admin_flag safe_mode off
      </Files>
        </IfModule>
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
        Require local
        ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
    </Directory>
</IfModule>`

Comment: And that is what I have found in XAMP_FORBIDDEN.html.var `Content-language: en
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Body:----------en--
<!--#set var="TITLE" value="Access forbidden!"
--><!--#include virtual="include/top.html" -->

  <!--#if expr="v('REDIRECT_URL') =~ m:/$:" -->

    You don't have permission to access the requested directory.
    There is either no index document or the directory is read-protected.

  <!--#else -->

    You don't have permission to access the requested object.
    It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.

  <!--#endif -->`

Comment: It's worth mentioning, that I have indeed run XAMPP as the admin

Comment: Long story short. I re-installed XAMPP. It works. Apache, too. However when I do everything according to this guide [link](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-install-apache-on-windows/) it doesn't work. When accessing localhost, my website does not show up. Dashboard does

Comment: Code in comments is unreadable. All the relevant information should go into the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution

Essentially EVERYTHING that needs to be done

1. If you feel helpless; reinstall XAMPPP
2. When you do, please take a look at this website. https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-install-apache-on-windows/